# How to Re-initialize jquery.repeater correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery.repeater

I am using the jquery.repeater plugin in a form where a user can add extra fields via ajax callbacks. When I start the plugin normally with $('.repeater').repeater() I get multiple repeats...

How can I unbind or destroy to plugin to re-start it?

Comment: $('.repeater').unbind() or  $('.repeater').off()

Comment: Thanks Grumpy but its not working. Another thought ... the problem I am having is the new fields added are not posted inside the group (fields rewitten by the plugin) any other way to maybe add them ?...without destroying and starting the plugin?